# Synchronizing two Redux stores over a network?

Tags: javascript, ajax, redux, synchronization

I have a Redux store on my server and an identical Redux store on my client. Every time the user performs an action on the client, the state on the client is updated, and the change is described as a JSON object and sent to the server as an AJAX request. The server receives the request and updates its own store, perhaps adding a few changes of its own. A response is then sent back to the client and the client updates its own store accordingly.

Writing the logic to handle all of this (the packing/unpacking of data, the AJAX calls, and the update logic) is very tedious. It would be nice if there was some Redux extension that allowed seamless synchronization between two stores over a network. As in, you update the client store, and automagically all of the detected changes are sent to the server and the server is updated, and vice versa. I *could* send the entire state over the network each time a reducer is called on the client, but with a ~2 MB state, that would be extremely inefficient. Does such a synchronization library for Redux as I described exist?

(To be clear: I don't need to do any server-side validation since this is an internal, solo-use application. All validation is done client-side.)